# Reading thousands of files in clojure

Tags: clojure, io

I'm working on a script that needs to read tens of thousands of files from the disk. I'm trying to understand the best way to do this. I've run into a problem when I use `map` to do this using two packages [`clj-glob`](https://github.com/jkk/clj-glob) and [`clojure-mail`](https://github.com/owainlewis/clojure-mail):

```
(def sent-mail-paths
  (->> (str maildir-path "/*/_sent_mail/*")
       (glob) ;; returns files using clojure.java.io/as-file
       (map str) ;; i just want the paths
))

(def msgs
  (->> sent-mail-paths ;; 30K + paths
       (map mail/file->message)))
```

where the `glob` function in the first block comes from `clj-glob` and uses `as-file` to return a set of file objects (see [here](https://github.com/jkk/clj-glob/blob/master/src/org/satta/glob.clj)). I only want the path strings, so I do `(map str)`. The `mail/file->message` function in the second block uses `with-open` along with the java `FileInputStream` class to read the files (see [here](https://github.com/owainlewis/clojure-mail/blob/master/src/clojure_mail/core.clj#L38)).

The trouble I am encountering is that this code causes an error the moment I try to process the files in the resulting lazy sequence by doing evensomething like:

```
(count msgs)
```

The error is:

> (Too many open files in system)

The only way I've been able to get the job done here is to use `doseq`:

```
(def msgs (->> list-of-paths ;; 30K+ paths
               (map mail/file->message)))

(def final (atom []))
(doseq [x result]
  (swap! final conj (mail/file->message x)))
```

My question is whether this is the best (only?) way to accomplish this process without opening thousands and thousands of files at once? I don't fully understand why I can't use the lazy sequence that is returned by `map`. Why does that end up opening tons of files.

One thing, incidentally, that I noticed is that `clj-glob`, which is not a well-maintained package, does not use `with-open` when it calls `as-file`...

Comment: Sorry, can you please post your actual code for process? Lazy evaluation isn’t asynchronicity or parallelism, items get processed one by one, the approach should work unless you have a handle leak.

Comment: The place people get into trouble with lazy seqs and files is where they return a lazy sequence of the file contents - unless you are careful you can close the file before it’s done or leak the file completely. This isn’t that:-)

Comment: Finally, is your last part really verbatim? You define results then use result. You also define results using the map process and then later on you call process again... Thanks!

Comment: Why not `(map process list-of-paths)`? What am I missing? If you want parallelism you can use `(pmap process list-of-paths)`...

Comment: Hmmm, I will update the question with some code. I thought I understood the problem in terms of why it didn't work, but that seems not to be the case. I definitely can get away with sequential access, and in fact that's what I am trying to do.

Comment: as-file is a red herring here - the java File objects are not tied to open files, they’re just glorified path strings.

Comment: Can you share the code for `mail/file->message` and `process`?

Comment: OK, having now read all the surrounding code I’m struggling to manage this by inspection. There doesn’t seem to be an obvious file leak. Might have time to boot up later or maybe someone will beat me to it:-)

Comment: @ReutSharabani it's the use of `map` that's causing the error "Too many open files in system".

Comment: @pete23 I just got it to work with `map` writing my own simplified fn to grab the paths instead of using `clj-glob`. I wonder if the problem lies in `clj-glob`, which is not well-maintained. Although, I don't immediately see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you open/close the files correctly, there's a chance that during the execution of the program you hit an internally defined limit on the number of file descriptors that you program can have (this is common on long-lived programs such as microservices).

You can read here on how to look up what that limit is currently and how to increase it: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/

Comment: Opening and closing a file is file descriptor neutral. Only opening large numbers of files (or sockets) simultaneously or leaking them will cause this.

Comment: I ran into this situation where a service would accept a volume of requests that it might cause a large number of files open at a given time, before all the files could be closed, causing the limit to be hit.